# Append property value to c# model value using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to return the List of records with Id and name, where the name will be appended with the domain as name(domain) if the names are non-unique and it will again append with code if domain is also non-unique, such as name(domain)(code).

To be Clear
name - for unique names,
name(domain) - for duplicated names
name(domain)(code) - for duplicated codes.

Below are the sample data and expected data

```
**Sample Data**
var filter = new List<Record>()
{
     new Record { Id = 011, Name = "OAKLAWN", Code = 123, Domain = "p1000"},
     new Record { Id = 012, Name = "OAKLAWN", Code = 124 , Domain = "p2000"},
     new Record { Id = 013, Name = "OAKLAWN", Code = 125 , Domain = "p3000"},
     new Record { Id = 014, Name = "OAKLAWN", Code = 126 , Domain = "p4000"},
     new Record { Id = 015, Name = "OAKLAWN", Code = 127 , Domain = "p5000"},
     new Record { Id = 016, Name = "PEAKLAWN", Code = 111 , Domain = "p6000"},
     new Record { Id = 017, Name = "PERKLAWN", Code = 124 , Domain = "p6000"},
     new Record { Id = 018, Name = "QUCKLAWN", Code = 122 , Domain = "p6000"}
};

**expected return data**
{ Id = 011, Name = "OAKLAWN(p1000)"},   
{ Id = 012, Name = "OAKLAWN(p2000)(124)"},  
{ Id = 013, Name = "OAKLAWN(p3000)"},   
{ Id = 014, Name = "OAKLAWN(p2000)(126)"},  
{ Id = 015, Name = "OAKLAWN(p5000)"},
{ Id = 016, Name = "PEAKLAWN"},
{ Id = 017, Name = "PERKLAWN"},
{ Id = 018, Name = "QUCKLAWN"}
```

How can I achieve this using c# LINQ.

.NET fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2UdaxY

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var records = filter.GroupBy(
        r => r.Name,
        (key, group) => group.Select(r => new
        {
            r.Id,
            Name = group.Count() == 1
                ? key
                : group.Count(x => x.Domain == r.Domain) == 1
                    ? $"{key}({r.Domain})"
                    : $"{key}({r.Domain})({r.Code})"
        })
    )
    .SelectMany(r => r)
    .ToArray();
```

.NET fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tIPZOR

Comment: Works perfectly as I expected, Also, how can I compare the case sensitive options but returns the same as given. Comparing "OAKLAWN and oaklawn" but the options name should return both small and block letters?

Comment: @Virat Check this fork https://dotnetfiddle.net/MmICvV

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have been trying from a few hours and you helped me with it, appreciated!!